# How convert string to int with Symfony Serializer

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, denormalized

I'm trying to denormalize an array into an object, but when the denormalize method comes across a code field that is a number, it gets an error since it is a string in the array, maybe it's fashionable to fix it

```
{
  "name": "Exception",
  "message": "The type of the \"code\" attribute for class \"App\\Http\\Response\\Flight\\DriverResponse\" must be one of \"int\" (\"string\" given).",
  "code": 0,
  "type": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Exception\\NotNormalizableValueException",
  "file": "/app/vendor/symfony/serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php",
  "line": 445,
  "stack-trace": [
    "#0 /app/vendor/symfony/serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php(331): Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer->validateAndDenormalize('App\\\\Http\\\\Respon...', 'code', '1', 'array', Array)",
    "#1 /app/vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php(185): Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer->denormalize(Array, 'App\\\\Http\\\\Respon...', 'array', Array)",
    "#2 /app/src/Http/Response/Transformer.php(96): Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Serializer->denormalize(Array, 'App\\\\Http\\\\Respon...', 'array')",
    "#3 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Response\\Transformer->App\\Http\\Response\\{closure}(Array)",
    "#4 /app/src/Http/Response/Transformer.php(98): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)",
    "#5 /app/src/Http/Controllers/Api/Flight/DriverController.php(124): App\\Http\\Response\\Transformer->transform(Object(yii\\data\\SqlDataProvider), 'drivers', 'App\\\\Http\\\\Respon...')",
    "#6 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\Flight\\DriverController->actionIndex()",
    "#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
    "#8 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)",
    "#9 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('index', Array)",
    "#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('Api/Flight/driv...', Array)",
    "#11 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))",
    "#12 /app/web/index.php(14): yii\\base\\Application->run()",
    "#13 {main}"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it, just need to pass this setting `[AbstractObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT => true]`

```
$this->serializer->denormalize(
    $array,
    $class,
   'array',
   [AbstractObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT => true]
);
```

Comment: Maybe you should force the type when you're setting it into the property. If you expect and int, it should always be an int, otherwise (in some other context not strictly related to serialization) you could fall into troubles.

Comment: At this point, I mapped data from a database that was a string on the DTO